# Installing Ubuntu Server on Dell R710 with HW RAID disabled

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, dell-poweredge

I disabled **Enable Controller BIOS control**, then disabled HW RAID from the BIOS setup screen, then booted with a live Ubuntu Desktop 11 CD only to clear RAID's metadata based on the information on that [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21267/why-doesnt-the-installer-see-all-of-my-hard-drives). But when Ubuntu is loaded (GUI), I opened the terminal and issued the os probing command using sudo, it returned nothing ! And no drives could be seen so the dmraid command didn't find anything to work on !

<strike>And when I enter the boot screen to chose a device to boot from, I can't find the "Hard drive C:" label which has my USB in it's menu. But now it's gone ! I've been messing a lot with the BIOS config but I'm not sure which mistake did I make.</strike>

It's all about clearing all the RAID data from the disks for Ubuntu Server installation to see the disks and continue the installation using Ubuntu's RAID configurations.

Comment: Which RAID controller do you have?

Comment: I'm currently away from the machine, I'll tell you when I have this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a good RAID controller then why would you try and mess around with software RAID?

If you have a good controller, and you disable it, then you obviously won't be able to see the drive because they are physically connected to the RAID controller.  They are not like fakeraid on motherboards where you flip a switch and change the mode of the SATA controller.

If you want to see individual drives, then re-enable the controller, and then go into the controller setup, and then break all the volumes.  Then you may need to do something to make the disks available for JBOD (just a bunch of disks),  or you might not have to do anything other then leave them un-configured.

Comment: I need to setup the RAID1E (RAID10) schema for my drives but I only found RAID1 and RAID5 available for the HW controller, probably because I only have 3 drives. Are you saying I need to physically disconnect the RAID controller ?

Comment: I am saying that if you have the H700,H800, then the drives are connected to the controller.  If you disable the controller, then you disable the drives.  What you need to do is go into the configuration for the controller and simply tell it to show the individual drives to your system.  You don't want to disable one of those.

Comment: What I did is that I deleted all "Virtual Drives", I thought that would do it but it didn't. I must have missed something.